# wxWidgets - Splitting project into multiple files

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, code-organization

I am very new to C++, I'm making this music application using `wxWidgets`, this is my first project in C++. As of now, I have 4 files, `app.hpp` and `app.cpp` which has a class that inherits from `wxApp` that launches the application, and `frame.hpp` and `frame.cpp` which holds the base frame and panel, and all the widgets, and their appropriate functions. I want to move all the functions to a separate file, but I get some errors like there is this function in `frame.cpp`

```
void Frame::ClearPlaylist(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    mediaCtrl->Stop();

    playlistBox->Clear();
}
```

I tried moving it in another file called `command.cpp` and created a new class called command and prefixed all functions to `Command:: ....`  and somethings like the `playlistBox` here, is a widget which I want in `frame.cpp` only, as it is a widget, so I did `#include frame.hpp` and prefixed it with `Frame::playlistBox`, but that gave a error saying `invalid use of non static data member`. So do I have to make everything in `frame.hpp` a static object? Or if anyone has a better solution for organizing a project like this please do share.

Comment: Non-static member functions require an object to act upon.  `Frame frame; frame.playlistBox();`

Comment: Ah! So `::` are only for static functions and variables?

Comment: The `::` is the scope resolution operator.  The class is a scope, similar to now a namespace is a scope.

Comment: So, `::` won't work, in another file, even if I `#include` the corresponding header file, that has that class declaration?

Comment: It should work.  I suspect your header file is incorrect, or you are compiling+linking your program together incorrectly.

Comment: @apoorv569, You absolutely should lern C++ first or at least become familiar with the language so you are comfortable. Don't try to use the library such as `wxWidgets` to learn - learn the basics first. wxWidgets is an advanced library. Get to college and learn the language. Then when you are comfortable - start using wxWidgets. The library is not a tool to learn the language it is using. Or keep using wxPython - I remember you were using it before.

Comment: @apoorv569, agreeing with above mentioned comment. If you are really new to C++, it would be to your best interest to learn and practice C++ and then move on to learning an advanced GUI library such as wxWidgets.